# How to show item center in recyclerview in gridlayout

Tags: android, android-studio

I want show items in center position when the item is in odd position. I tried using gridview & recyclerview gridlayout but not working. Is there any way??

Comment: Can you show an example with images that how you want to show items in the center?

Comment: take more information please.... you want item is center of View or center in list of recycler view?